# Parallels: Copy and Paste not working

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtual-machine, parallels

I am running Parallels build 4.0.3384 (the latest at the time of writing), on Mac OS X 10.5.7, with Windows 7 RC1 as my VM

I am unable to copy and paste from the host to the VM and vice versa. This is really annoying, any ideas?

Comment: Which copy/paste methods have you tried using? Just wondering if you found that right-click copy/paste worked but keyboard ctrl-c then apple-v (etc) didn't...?

Comment: All of them ... :-)

Comment: [Chealion, related to the tag cleanup, maybe you're interested in this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/please-could-we-combine-the-osx-and-macosx-tags]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I just sorted this out. I shut the machine, then went configure > Features > Services

Then unchecked Share clipboard, then ok. Closed parallels so the machine configuration saved to disk.

Opened parallels went back and re-selected Share clipboard then fired up the machine and ... ta da ... fixed.

Update:

Well no it wasn't fixed as the problem came back, however upgrading to Beta5 has solved it 100%

Comment: this worked on build 7.0.15052
It's funny that these clowns haven't fixed this same bug yet eh? lol

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you have .NET 3.5 installed on the Windows VM, it will prevent copy/paste from working.   Remove 3.5 (2.0, 3.0 seem fine) and it should fix it.   At least that's my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes reinstalling "Parallels Tools" helps.

Select "Virtual Machine - Reinstall parallels tools" in the menu, while your VM is running.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are having issues with ClipBoard Copy/Paste between Windows and Mac OS X, my problem was that I enabled "Isolate Mac from Windows" option under Security in Configure/Options tab.

Disabling that and rebooting the guest OS seems to have taken care of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In app "windows 10" > in menubar "actions" > menu choice "configure" > tab "options" > sidebar choose "more options" > enable checkbox "share mac clipboard"

[image: parallels mac windows clipboard copypaste]